# IUPAC name of trimethyl amine

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

What is the IUPAC name of trimethyl amine? Can we give it an IUPAC name or not? If not then does it mean the IUPAC naming system is limited?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Your question shows zero effort and might be closed as such. Edit it to include more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course there's a IUPAC name for trimethyl amine. If IUPAC wouldn't be able to name such simple molecules it would be completely useless.

The systematic name is: **N,N-Dimethylmethanamine**

Comment: While your answer is correct, we prefer to not spoon-feed the askers. Such an info is right there on Wikipedia.

Comment: @PrittBalagopal well, then let us just be consequent and delete such questions right away. Downvoting a correct answer is even worse than answering on a pretty effortless question. (and some language versions of wikipedia don't list IUPAC names...)

Comment: When you hover over the downvote button, it says: *this post is not useful*. I believe this is so, as it doesn't help the community by helping askers who cannot help themselves. We *are* closing the question. You were apparently quite quick to answer it.